# Is this possible to run html/css or JavaScript in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, ckeditor

I am using `CKEditor` asp.net page for allowing client to easily edit/format text. Also i am using tabs option within `CKEditor` as shown in the fig. attached. But tabs are not working at all. Initially i have created tabs withJS. I thought it’s the JS that not working with `CKEditor` so i have chosen alternative solution using css3. But tabs are still not working in `CKEditor`. I have searched on `CKEditor forum` but unable to get good resource or help.
For css3 I am using `checkbox` hidden through opacity 0; but checkboxes are not working in `CKEditor`. What comes finally in my mind is `CKEditor` doesn’t run html.  Is there any solution for this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor secures JavaScript code so it's not executed to prevent unexpected editor behavior. Also mouse/keyboard events from form elements are captured for robust editing, making regular manipulation impossible. The conclusion is: **editor is for creating rich content, not for rendering layouts**.

The simplest advice I have is to put the editor one level down. Namely:

1. Create tabs.
2. Make each tab title an [inline editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) (it must be a block element).
3. Put an inline instance of CKEditor into each single tab contents.
4. Serialize your tabs when saving. It's easy.

**Bonus**: With a little help from [ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) (since 4.1) you can prevent the layout from being destroyed by thoughtless users. Basically restrict which plugins are loaded for every editor to manipulate the result of the editing.

Comment: Something like this seems like a good testcase for the new Widgets feature. Just saying ;-)

Comment: Hmm... In some cases it could be a case for Widgets. But only if tabs group is meant to be "inline". Otherwise, tabs should be edited separately and entire "widget" should be separated from editor.